# Acer laptop brightness and sound(Dolby Home theater) issues

Tags: 16.04, sound, acer, aspire-one

My small problem on my Acer laptop (ASPIRE series), is that the sound seems low and sounds like a crashed-like sound.

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
- Model: Aspire 4736Z.

Here it is @DavidFoster

[Please click this link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23415504/)

Comment: What specific laptop model is it ?

Comment: @JonasCz, Here it is ASPIRE 4736Z.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thank you for guiding me, I asked my first question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster here it is [http://askubuntu.com/questions/844431/acer-aspire-4736z-brightness-issue]

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`, `aplay -l` and `pactl list sinks` as well as the content of `~/.pulse/default.pa` (if it exists)? You can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone out there who can answer my question?